# How do I reference the picture I just took in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm writing an app that allows the user to take a picture and then shows it in an image view.

I get that I need to write a line of code similar to the following: `_imageView.image = picker.image;`, but I'm not sure what I need to substitute for `picker.image`.  That is what I currently have and it gives me an error.

Basically, what I'm asking is how do I reference the picture that was just taken?  Where does this picture go (in memory?) after you take it?  How can I reference it later (like for displaying and saving and that sort of stuff)?

I've already read the official Apple documentation and looked at a few tutorials and the answer doesn't seem to be in any of them.  As I've mentioned in previous posts, I tend to have a lot of trouble parsing the Apple documentation, so it's been mostly useless for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following delegate method to get whatever picture a user picked from the photo picker view

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];
    image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; 

}
```

Comment: Do I need to call `[self imagePickerController]` from somewhere after I write this method?  How do I implement it in the code?

Comment: No, it's a delegate method. It's called by the UIImagePickerController Delegate. You need to of course add this delegate to your header file. The delegate is UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

Comment: Maybe I'm not quite sure what a delegate is, then.  How is this implemented in the code?  How is it called in the code?  When does it run?

Comment: They are some of the most useful things you can know how to use. Check out this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNmZEXNQheE

Comment: I just finished watching it and I have to admit that I didn't understand very much of it (like when the method or delegate is supposed to be running).  Maybe I'm missing the concept entirely.  Is there a way to do this without delegates?

Comment: How do I "add this delegate to [my] header file"?

Answer (score 0):

call the cameraTapped method on tapping your camera button

```
-(IBAction)cameraTapped:(id)sender 
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    if ([UIImagePickerController  isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    else
        [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
     // photo
     _imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: When does the `imagePickerController` run?  How do I call it?  I don't see it called anywhere.  `[self imagePickerController]`?

Comment: you don't need to call it. this is delegate method. it will get called automatically as soon as you click the photo

Comment: Is there a way to do this without delegates?  I'm really not understanding what is going on with them despite having read a few tutorials and watched a video.

Comment: No, you can't do it in any way. then first learn basic this of Obejctive-C