# How do I call delegates in iOS programming? How does the app know when the code should run if I never call it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding delegates in iOS programming.  When I write a delegate in the code, when does it get called?  How do I call it?  If I don't call it, per se, how does it know when it's supposed to run?

I feel like an idiot, but I've read a few tutorials at this point and I just can't grasp the concept.

For some code I'm trying to work on, see the responses for my code at: [How do I reference the picture I just took in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074289/how-do-i-reference-the-picture-i-just-took-in-ios)

Comment: This question is really vague and unclear. Do you have a specific example you are working with?

Comment: The code won't run if you *never* call it

Comment: @rmaddy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074289/how-do-i-reference-the-picture-i-just-took-in-ios

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Then how would I call it?  `[self nameOfTheDelegateMethod]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your other question then understand that you don't call the delegate. The class that provides the delegate will call your method when it is appropriate to do. You provide the delegate method and you tell the class that you are its delegate. Then that's it. When the class is ready, it will call the delegate method that you implemented.

In the case of the image picker controller, it will call your `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method once the user choose or takes a picture. It will call your `imagePickerControllerDidCancel:` method if the user cancels.

Just make sure you set the `delegate` property in the image picker controller instance so it knows who to contact when it is ready.

Update - somewhere in the implementation of `UIImagePickerController` there is code along the following lines:

```
// The user has taken a picture, tell the delegate
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)]) {
    [self.delegate imagePickerController:self didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:infoDictionary];
}
```

In this case, `self.delegate` is your class instance.

Comment: How does is then know when the code is supposed to run?  Does it just divine it from the stars?  Are the names static and that's how it works, such that each delegate is a static, predetermined name that cannot be changed and runs at a prespecified time?  I'm sorry, I'm just having an extremely difficult time grasping this concept and any help at this point is definitely appreciated.

Comment: Look at the `UIImagePictureControllerDelegate` protocol. Yes, the names of the methods are pre-defined. They are defined by the protocol. Once the user takes a picture, the `UIImagePickerController` checks to see if the object set as its `delegate` implements the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`method. If it does, then the image picker controller calls that specific method on its delegate (your class). The result is that your method is called. There's no magic.

Comment: So it's sort of like overloading class functions if the original functions that you're overloading are empty?

Comment: Not really. There's nothing to override when working with protocol methods. See my updated answer.

Comment: I think I've got it now, even if I don't quite understand what is going on or what I'm doing.  Thanks so much for helping!  No one else got me this far before with delegates.