# What does it mean when a view is not in the window hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Okay, I've tried to implement a delegate method on a `UIImagePickerController` as stated by @MichaelKing in a previous post of mine.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];
image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; }
```

However, I get the following error in my code: `Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0xc464f10> on <RPFlipsideViewController: 0xc66a270> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

I really don't understand what this means, and searching for it online, but haven't found anything that I've been able to understand.  Can someone please clarify?  Maybe I still don't understand the whole delegate thing?

Here is my previous post, for reference: [How do I reference the picture I just took in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074289/how-do-i-reference-the-picture-i-just-took-in-ios)

Comment: Somewhere else in your code you must be trying to present a `UIImagePickerController` instance.  You're using a `RPFlipsideViewController` to present it but that controller isn't the one that has a view on-screen at the time.

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes, this is true.  I'm trying to present a `UIImagePickerController` from `RPFlipsideViewController`.  How do I get this to work?  I just want the camera to pop up and I have it doing so.  There are no code errors.

Comment: To get rid of the warning, the `RPFlipsideViewController` would have to be presented or otherwise made part of the view controller hierarchy before it presented anything.  You don't show how that controller is being used so I can't tell you anything more specific.

Comment: @PhillipMills How do I make it part of the view controller hierarchy?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html

Comment: @PhillipMills I keep forgetting to put the disclaimer in, but I don't understand that Apple developer docs at all.  They've never made sense to me, no matter how many times I read them.  Can you please just explain what I type to make it part of the view controller hierarchy?

Comment: Not really.  There's no one magic answer; it depends on everything else you're doing with views and view controllers.  (Also, your "disclaimer" isn't much use...nobody's going to rewrite all the docs for you and most of them are necessary.  Maybe if you find them that bad you could try some introductory books....)

Comment: @PhillipMills I've already read a couple of introductory books on iOS development and I can't find anything about this on them; I think they don't cover that far in depth this sort of operation and their dealing with cameras only has to deal with using the button to take a picture.  I think I don't understand what the term "window hierarchy" means, or really how to begin to debug the problem.  A lot of these tutorials just come up as gibberish, with never-ending trees of programming jargon that I have to look up.  I've spent a couple of weeks of entire days trying to do slog through tutorials.

Comment: I don't know what to say....  If you're bugged by "programming jargon" and find reading tech books and documentation to be a pain, you should probably stop torturing yourself.  :)

Comment: @PhillipMills I'm in a class and have to get this done.  I've been programming for a decade now and have never had the sort of frustration that I've had with Objective-C before.

Answer (score 0):

The view controller's view must be on the screen (not necessarily visible) which is it must be in the hierarchy somewhere.
Without being in the current view hierarchy there is no graphics context in which to present the picker.

Comment: Can you rephrase that?  I don't understand what you just wrote.  Sorry.